# Android: Transform a bitmap into an input stream

Tags: android

How do you transform a `Bitmap` into an `InputStream`?

I would like to use this `InputStream` as input to the `ETC1Util.loadTexture()` function.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

This might work

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 0 /*ignored for PNG*/, bos); 
byte[] bitmapdata = bos.toByteArray();
ByteArrayInputStream bs = new ByteArrayInputStream(bitmapdata);
```

Comment: It's not an ideal solution, because it causes bitmap bytes to be 2 times in memory: in bitmapdata and in bos. So it's a waste of memory.

Comment: @Malachiasz If u know a better way, add it as an answer and mention it as comment to my answer. Future people will notice it.

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43669060/4515489) reports that EXIF data is lost in compression, so if someone is wanting the input stream in order to read EXIF info from a bitmap in memory then another method would be needed.

Comment: Why do you need to `compress` it? You compress it to a `PNG` but what if the image is a gif? Would it apply PNG-compression which could increase the size? What does that actually do?

Comment: @JohnSardinha I haven't written java or developed for android for over 5 years. You might wanna ask this as another question.

Answer (score 7):

This is my way:

```
// Your Bitmap.
Bitmap bitmap = XXX;  

int byteSize = bitmap.getRowBytes() * bitmap.getHeight();
ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(byteSize);
bitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer(byteBuffer);  

// Get the byteArray.
byte[] byteArray = byteBuffer.array();

// Get the ByteArrayInputStream.
ByteArrayInputStream bs = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArray);
```

Comment: A caution about using getRowBytes(), "As of KITKAT, this method should not be used to calculate the memory usage of the bitmap. Instead, see getAllocationByteCount()." - from [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#getRowBytes())

Comment: On the other hand, getAllocationByteCount() requires API 19.