# is it necessary to save an image before sending it via FTP in Android app?

Tags: java, android, bitmap, ftp

I have a bitmap

`Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);`

and I want to send this bitmap to my server, like this

`ftpclient.storeFile("myserverpath", myBitmap);`

but I must send a file; I can't send a bitmap. Do I have to save this bitmap into a file on the phone and then load that file and send it? Or is there a simpler way to do this? I'm using Apache Commons for FTP. Thanks.

Comment: Since there doesn't appear to be an ftp class in the Android SDK, it would entirely depend on what library you're using for ftp.

Comment: I'm using Apache Commons, if that helps

Comment: Not for me. I would like to hear the ftp class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `.storeFile()` accepts an `InputStream` and not a `File`, it's not necessary to save the `Bitmap` first. Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7698445/523215) to get an `InputStream` from a `Bitmap`.