# Can I upload an image in a bitmap variable to Amazon S3 in Android?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, bitmap

I am working on an app that needs to upload pictures to Amazon. I am uploading like this:

```
s3Client.putObject( new PutObjectRequest(myBucket, myKey, myFile) );
```

Which works like a charm. The thing is that now I need to compress the picture before uploading it. I found this:

```
Bitmap original = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(...);
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
original.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
Bitmap compressed = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray()));
```

That still needs to be tested though. So yeah, I could save the bitmap and use that new file to upload to Amazon, but I would have twice the same image in memory which is not required. I dont want to replace the original either if possible since I might want to use it later. I guess I could create a temporary file and delete it afterwards, but if there is a direct way to upload the bitmap variable, that would be great.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First look at the answer to this question: [Android: Transform a bitmap into an input stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7698409/android-transform-a-bitmap-into-an-input-stream)

Then use the [version of PutObjectRequest](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSAndroidSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/PutObjectRequest.html#PutObjectRequest(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.InputStream,%20com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.ObjectMetadata)) that takes an InputStream.

Comment: Oh I see. Basically, no `BitmapFactory.decodeStream(...)`. Perfect, that was exactly the references I need. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I am late to answer this question but try this out by sending byte[]/InputStream directly.Make sure you provide content length in metadata.

```
private static void uploadToS3(final String OBJECT_KEY, final byte[] bis)  {
        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(bis);

        ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata();
        metadata.setContentType("image/jpeg");
        /*Out of memory can be caused if you don't specify minimum metadata of Content Length of your inputstream*/
        Long contentLength = Long.valueOf(bis.length);
        metadata.setContentLength(contentLength);
        PutObjectRequest putObjectRequest = new PutObjectRequest("BUCKET_NAME",
                OBJECT_KEY,/*key name*/
                is,/*input stream*/
                metadata);
        try {
            PutObjectResult putObjectResult = s3.putObject(putObjectRequest);
        } catch (AmazonServiceException ase) {
            System.out.println("Error Message:    " + ase.getMessage());
            System.out.println("HTTP Status Code: " + ase.getStatusCode());
            System.out.println("AWS Error Code:   " + ase.getErrorCode());
            System.out.println("Error Type:       " + ase.getErrorType());
            System.out.println("Request ID:       " + ase.getRequestId());
        } catch (AmazonClientException ace) {
            System.out.println("Error Message: " + ace.getMessage());
        } finally {
            if (is != null) {
                try {
                    is.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }
            }
        }
    }
```